# Does terminating a cpanel account in WHM also delete emails on the server?

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

A site I know longer use was apparently getting hit with some spam and has 5GBs of webmail.

If I terminate the entire account from WHM will this also free up those 5GBs, or do I need to do this separately? If separate, how can I do that?

It is the default email account that was created, so I can't just delete that email account from cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes terminating the cPanel account will delete all the emails also and will free your 5 GB space